# Anidar Layouts mediante código

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Ya he añadido un layout a otro mediante código, pero en este caso en concreto no consigo que me funcione. Si los añado con un inlcude en los xml funciona correctamente, se trata de replicar en código los include de los .xml. Los layouts son estos:

Layout padre (parent.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/child_1" /> esto funciona correctamente -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Primer layout hijo (child_1.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/child_1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/media_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_1_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- First row: header -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_row"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                ... />

            <TextView
                ... />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Second row: ... -->
        <!-- <include layout="@layout/child_2" />  Esto funciona correctamente  -->
        Incluir child_2 por código aquí. Esto no funcina. 

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Segundo layout hijo (child_2.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/child_2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Y el código java con el que intento replicar los include anteriores:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent));

LinearLayout child_1 = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_1, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.child_1));

LinearLayout child_1_2 = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_1, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.child_1_2));

LinearLayout child_2 = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_2, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.child_2));

child_1_2.addView(child_2);
parent.addView(child_1);
```

El layout parent añade correctamente al child_1, pero el child_1 no muestra el child_2.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado con la ayuda de la versión en ingles. Lo dejo aquí por si alguien tiene un problema similar.

El child_1_2 debe instanciarse así:

```
LinearLayout child_1_2 = child_1.findViewById(R.id.child_1_2);
```

Y el código java es el siguiente (solo dos líneas):

```
child_1_2.addView (child_2);
parent.addView (child_1);
```